# Supabase Javascript Realtime subscription useState not in sync

Tags: supabase, supabase-js, supabase-realtime

When calling the callFunc outside of this subscription context everything works fine and all my items are logged. However when I add a new Task callFunc will get called but the logged state is the empty state of of starting my application. How can this be?

```
const receivedEvent = (payload: any) => {
  console.log(payload);
  callFunc();
};

const callFunc = () => {
  console.log(items);
};

useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = supabase
    .channel("Task")
    .on(
      "postgres_changes",
      { event: "INSERT", schema: "public", table: "Task" },
      receivedEvent
    )
    .subscribe();
  return () => {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Where are you setting items? It doesn't seem like you are updating items anywhere in this code...

Comment: Of course because this is only a snippet of my whole project. Items hold some values at the point where it should be logged

Comment: It would be helpful to understand the full context of where this data is being set, otherwise it's hard to pin point the problem. I suggest trying to create a minimal reproducing example...

Comment: It seems like supabase uses the ref of the initialization of the useEffect above. I fixed it by using a ref, which I update every time I update my state.